# Xcode 5 Unit Test precompiled header importing <RestKit/RestKit.h>

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, header

I have an Xcode workspace that uses `RestKit 2.0` where the precompiled header imports  `<RestKit/RestKit.h>`. When I try to run unit tests I get a 'file not found' error in the precompiled header on the `RestKit-header` files.

What do I have to do to make the test target see the `RestKit` libraries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check if the Pods project linked with your tests target.

Add `link_with ['YourTarget', 'YourTargetTests']` and then `pod update`.